# MVC partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

Learning MVC and despite making good ground, confused on this one.

So I built some CRUD scaffolded objects from an entity. The create page I amended to include some dropdown lists. I chose to use a partial view and everything works great!

Now I've come to the edit part of the functionality. Using the same partial view I used in the create, I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'FiveADayMVC2.Models.fad_userFoods', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'FiveADayMVC2.Models.fad_mealType'.

Details: My code fails here

```
@Html.Partial("fad_mealTypeDdlPartial")
```

This is located in a view called `edit.cshtml`.
`fad_mealTypeDdlPartial.cshtml` consists of

```
@model FiveADayMVC2.Models.fad_mealType
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.mealTypeID, ViewBag.mealTypeItems as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select Meal Type.............")
```

My model looks thus:

```
public partial class fad_mealType
{
    public int mealTypeID { get; set; }
    public string mealTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

As I've said, it goes through all the code to populate the `ViewBag` with the correct list of items. Just fails when rendering the view. An added confusion is I have another dropdown list on the page for food items and this works perfectly if I remove the meal type ddl. The code for this is identical in structure (but obviously references the relevant food model). Any guidance as to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated. And I realize it reads a little confusing so what else do you need from me?

Comment: The error is self explanatory (your passing the wrong model to the view). And go to the help files and learn how to format your question and code

Comment: This doesn't looks like relevant code. You're not passing any model into the view here: `@Html.Partial("fad_mealTypeDdlPartial")` but exception clearly says that you're passing model having type `fad_userFoods`.

Comment: My edit.cshtml has @model FiveADayMVC2.Models.fad_userFoods
And like it says Stephen, I appreciate it's not clearly explained, hence I said what further information do you need!!

Comment: First read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Then change your code to `@Html.Partial("fad_mealTypeDdlPartial", new fad_mealType())`

Comment: Thank you Stephen and Andy. A combination of you two and Ronni has solved the problem. Adding the model has done the trick. And yes I will read the formatting link you provided for future questions, of which there will be many no doubt. Next step is populating the ddl with the value from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing the "edit" View the `@Html.Partial("fad_mealTypeDdlPartial")` call is on, has a `@model` type of "userFoods".

But your doing a `@Html.Partial("fad_mealTypeDdlPartial")` without passing in a model for the view.

Either use `Html.Action("SomeActionThatReturnsAPartialWithModel")`, or pass in a model when you use `@Html.Partial("fad_mealTypeDdlPartial", SOMEMEALTYPEMODEL)`

`@Html.Action()` runs an action in your controller, that can then return the view.